# how to bring the icons closer?

Tags: android, appbar

I am having my app bar with three icons on it. The space between them looks quite high. How to get them closer

[image]

the following is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: check for icon height/width. That might be an issue to this. Make sure that that is as guidelines.

Comment: I think the icons are square thats why they are arranged so spaciously. So get then closer icons should be in rectangular shape

Comment: I think the icons are square thats why they are arranged so spaciously. So get then closer icons should be in rectangular shape

Comment: you can use  android:orderInCategory="50" while adding the items which follows ltr from 1 to 100

Answer (score 0):

Use this theme changing what you think needs to be changed but definitely experiment with the width and height values to find the ones that suit your needs.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/myActionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/myActionButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="myActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">

        <item name="android:width">80dp</item>

        <item name="android:height">80dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: This is headed in the right direction, but it's the `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` attributes that they'd want to adjust.